# Updating UILabel not working

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I created the label in scene editor and I'm trying to update it via the click of a button but every time I click the button I get this error at the timeLabel line "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) "

this is the code I'm using, it should have a value so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

```
 @IBAction func stopButton(_ sender: Any) {
    endTime = DispatchTime.now()
    print ("\(endTime)")
    timerStarted = false
    let start = startTime.uptimeNanoseconds
    let end = endTime.uptimeNanoseconds

    let nanoTime = end - start
     let timeInterva = Double(nanoTime) / 1_000_000_000
    let total = Double(timeInterva) * hourRate
    print("\(timeInterva)")
    timerLabel.text = String(total)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your @IBOutlet to timerLabel is likely not hooked up. Go to your storyboard -> ViewController -> Click on the ViewController in the Scene Hierarchy -> Connections Inspector on the top left (see Screenshot) where the timerLabel is, and make sure you're seeing something like this:

[image]

And not something like this:
[image]

Comment: Hmm strange, I had linked it previously, not sure what happened but I went back and relinked and its working now. Thanks!

Comment: @Mick maybe you changed the name of the property before. If that happens then you really have to relink it.